# Issue with a section content

Tags: css, html, article

I have a issue with a section in its content.

If you see everything i write in the section goes outside of it and the section appear to be empty!

HTML:

```
<section id="scopri">
<article id="scopridettagli">
    <div id="scoprisx">
        <ul class="scopriul">
            <li>
                <p class="scopri">problemone</p>
            </li>
            <br />
            <li>
                <p class="scopri">problemtwo</p>
            </li>
            <br />
            <li>
                <p class="scopri">problemthree</p>
            </li>
            <br />
            <li>
                <p class="scopri">problemfour</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="scopridx">
        <ul class="scopriul">
            <li>
                <p class="scopri">stillproblemfive</p>
            </li>
            <br />
            <li>

                <p class="scopri">problemsix</p>
            </li>
            <br />
            <li>
                <p class="scopri">problemseven</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</article>
```

CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/giovapanasiti/yLtEy/3/

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Your markup is invalid:  only `li` elements can be children of `ul` elements, `br` tags are not allowed there.  Consider applying top/bottom margins to your `li` elements instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to `#scopridettagli` .. its height is collapsed due to its [floated descendants](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/)

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yLtEy/4/)

Comment: Thank you so much!! And thank you for the article you shared it's so usefull